# How to generate a printable output for a phonebook

Tags: java, printing, latex, formatting, swt

I'm developing a desktop software to manage people and telephones, and also to generate (export) a list of telephones (also with a summary of the cities) that can be printed (like pdf). The part of telephones management is ready and was made with java and swt/jface. Exporting the list in a print friendly format is what has become an issue.

I tried exporting the list in HTML with CSS, but the result is not the same in different browsers.
I was thinking about generating it in LaTeX, but creating an style is getting too complicated (need an A7 page size, smaller fonts...).

What file format can be used to export this list? Is there an easy way to generate printable stuff?

**Edit:** forgot to mention that the file will be sent to a company to be printed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a pdf, it will look the same no matter what browser they use.   You can use iText to create the pdf, it is fairly straight forward for a simple pdf.

Comment: This tutorial was very useful: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just draw an image, it will stay the same on different systems and its easy to print. by drawing it, you can style it like you imagine, without learning any document format. It should be easy to draw a simple table.

Comment: That's not a good idea because it will have lots of pages and I also need to create a summary... Could create an image per page though... but I need something more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Plain text is a very friendly format for me. Altough, this could be done with HTML and CSS, if you keep the style complexity level to a minimum. Try reading:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

And be careful when choosing your properties!

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I need a format to send to print in a graphics company.